# Unable to connect to wireless network and red cross appear

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, modem

I have encountered a network connectivity problem in Windows 7 Home edition Acer laptop.

I just subscribed to a 4G Internet service provider and got a new modem as a result. However, when I allow my laptop to detect the new wireless signal emitted from the new modem, my laptop showed that the modem signal (that is, dnakan_1D3B9D) gave a red cross mark. This is a link to the image I saw on the screen having the red cross mark (https://s15.postimg.org/ngg5frvkr/red_mark_cross.jpg). Thus, I have never been able to connect to the Internet for browsing purpose.

I have communicated with the Internet service provider and the instruction given by its technical officer is of no use. The instruction provided includes modem reset to default.

So, I am writing to seek helpful advice regarding new method to remove the red cross mark, allowing me to connect to the Internet. Please, assist me!

Comment: 4G network isn't that for phones? Can you access it with your phone? Could you please update your answer with some more details about the modem and service provider.

Comment: I am not sure about the 4G network for phone only. Yes, my phone can wirelessly connect to the modem. It is only my laptop has a problem with the modem as mentioned above. May I know what you need to know about the modem and service provider so that you can assist me to remove the red cross mark as shown in the URL given above?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I know what you are saying that your company is a Wireless Internet Service Provider (WISP) (This is in fact becoming more and more popular, I worked for one), It confuses people, the company uses 4G Radio that go to a modem just like any other ISP has modems.

Second, Here seems to be the problem and your solution:

It looks as if you already have settings on your laptop for this router, not sure how or why, but this does not matter, we need to get rid of them, so you can do this all over.

Here is a link to a Windows Help Section to get rid of the Saved Network (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252588(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_Anchor1) which is also noted below:

> **Credit: [Windows TechNet Help Pages](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/)**
>
> **To delete a wireless network connection**
>
> Starting Network and Sharing Center by using Control Panel
>
> - Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
>
> For Windows 7, do one of the following:
>
> - In Control Panel, in Adjust your computer’s settings, when View by is    set to Category, click Network and Internet, and then click
>     Network    and Sharing Center.
>
> OR
>
> - In Control Panel, in Adjust your computer’s settings, when View by is    set to either Large icons or Small icons, click Network and
>     Sharing    Center.
> - In the Tasks pane, click Manage wireless networks.
> - Right-click the connection you want to delete, and then click Remove    network.
> - In the Manage Wireless Networks - Warning dialog box, click OK.
> - The connection is removed from the list of wireless connections that    you can view or modify.

Now you should be able to go about connecting to the wireless network as you would any new Hotspot/Access Point, have your Network Key Handy and enter it when it ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get into the Wifi settings of the 4g wifi modem, change it from WPA/WPA2 to straight WPA. The wifi chipset in the Acer Laptop sometimes struggles with WPA2 compatibility. It will also help to change the Wifi Password.